# Push issue with heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku

I didn't have any issue with the git itself. I have committed all of my changes and code to my master branch, and pushed my commits and changes to heroku app.
System showed me messages that successfully have pushed the commits, so when I try to push the commits again it always shows me the message "Everything up-to-date".
But when I go into heroku website, it shows no app or commits that I have made. What can be the problem?

Comment: What steps did you follow to push your changes to heroku on the heroku CLI?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Instead of describing what you've done, please _show us_. And check your logs with `heroku logs`.